# No UDP connection to swarm service

Tags: python-3.x, docker-swarm

I`m try to develop a microsservice with docker swarm. I have a UDP server listen on port 27901. 
I have two Cases:

1. If I run the image locally and publish the ports I can send data from
   the localhost to the container.
2. If I deploy the service to a swarm with same ports published I get a connection refuesed.

In case 2 I dont understand the behaviour because the visualizer service I deploy with the same compose file is accessible.

DOCKERFILE

```
FROM python:3.6
EXPOSE 27901/udp
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./code/ /app
```

DOCKERCOMPOSE

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  data_receiver:
    image: data_receiver:latest
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 5s
    ports:
      - "27901:27901/udp"

  visualizer:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
```

Thanks for your time regards
MarLei

Comment: What happens when you add a network in your yaml file? Use a "network: -mynetwork" in each service section, and define a "networks: -mynetwork" at the end

Comment: @FrankLouwers thanks for your answer. I found the bug in my code. I try to bind the  socket to 127.0.0.1 and to hostname. But this didn´t work in swarm mode. The solution is to bind the socket to 0.0.0.0 so all incoming messeges are accepted.